# How can I read/write exact positions of a file in js while avoiding race conditions

Tags: javascript, database, semaphore

I am implementing a tree as a simple array (in the *C* sense of an array) that uses operations on the indices of the array instead of pointers. The tree will get very large, and I need it to persist. The simplest solutions would seem to be a generic file with all the data of the array simply strung together.

To access leaves of the tree I need the following:

- Ability to read/write a single  series of 32-byte items at *random* positions in the file.
- Ability to "lock" the file before doing a read/write so that other asynchronous calls to the tree functions will have to wait while the tree is being updated (because 1 update to the *tree abstraction*, requires multiple updates to the file itself).

I am using the `fs` module that comes with node for accessing the file system, however calling `open` does not lock it from other threads, and I dont see any documentation regarding it. Ideally I would not have to block more than just this one file, and it would not create significant overhead, as I will be doing 10s of millions of reads/writes to the tree (which is 100's of millions of reads/writes to the file).

Comment: So just use `mmap`

Comment: Why did you tag both [tag:c] and [tag:javascript]? There are very different solutions. In particular, most JS environments prohibit filesystem access.

Comment: You can do all that with a normal file, yes. Did you have a specific question?

Comment: ok, I'm using node.js, but the functions that seem relevant are `fs` which i think is the same in C. That's why the "C" tag. So far my plan is to use fs.open() which I believe is just a pointer, then fs.read() w relevant position/offset args. about to attempt fs.write() but i still don't know how to solve race conditions

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a `semephore`. Nothing really needed to happen at the operating system level. The semaphore just encloses my function inside `semephore.take(myTrie.put())`, and when called multiple times, it puts the containing functions into a queue, only calling each one after the previous has called `semephore.leave()` (which I'm calling during its resolve).